# Heroku app won't deploy and keeps crashing not sure if it is using my procfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

My app will just not load it keeps timing out and is giving me a `503 h10` error through my logs.

I have worked around the `uglifier` problem, added a `procfile`, looked to do a start script but unsure of what will work for that one. https://github.com/CarlSciz/Villain_Enterprise_

I have worked around the `uglifier` problem, added a `procfile`, looked to do a start script but unsure of what will work for that one. I have also added the bundler gem that it says it's missing.

```
2019-06-25T17:10:12.187805+00:00 app[web.1]: To update to the lastest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
2019-06-25T17:10:12.187811+00:00 app[web.1]: To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.0.2`
2019-06-25T17:10:12.187818+00:00 app[web.1]: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:263:in `bin_path'
2019-06-25T17:10:12.187825+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
2019-06-25T17:10:13.111607+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=villainenterprise.herokuapp.com request_id=9c8f5e4d-ec05-46cd-a953-6bcbbde90008 fwd="68.55.118.239" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-06-25T17:10:15.607654+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=villainenterprise.herokuapp.com request_id=a531d7a2-91ba-4f0b-b4d6-f19d1c2a675e fwd="68.55.118.239" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

it just will not load, even the local host won't load now.

Comment: Did you add a file called `procfile` or `Procfile`? The capital "P" is important.

Comment: can you include more of the log output?

Comment: Show what appears with this command: gem list bundler

Comment: It is with a capital "P" for Procfile.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem an hour ago. The bundler 2 update is still causing ripple effects throughout the Ruby world.

Running this in the command line (in the same directory as your app) fixed it for me:

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/bundler/heroku-buildpack-bundler2
```

As indicated by [this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/6784#issuecomment-438562046).

However, I can say that I am not sure why this is happening - perhaps it is a temporary glitch. Yesterday, I was able to deploy a different app to Heroku, without the need to run this command, and [this page on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1563) states that Bundler 2 should already be supported natively.